# iPhone UIScrollView Speed Check

Tags: iphone, scroll, uiscrollview

I know how to get the contentOffset on movement for a UIScrollView, can someone explain to me how I can get an actual number that represents the current speed of a UIScrollView while it is tracking, or decelerating?

Comment: Not a big deal but I put in the modern solution to this very old question down the bottom.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Have these properties on your UIScrollViewDelegate

```
CGPoint lastOffset;
NSTimeInterval lastOffsetCapture;
BOOL isScrollingFast;
```

Then have this code for your scrollViewDidScroll:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {    
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    NSTimeInterval timeDiff = currentTime - lastOffsetCapture;
    if(timeDiff > 0.1) {
        CGFloat distance = currentOffset.y - lastOffset.y;
        //The multiply by 10, / 1000 isn't really necessary.......
        CGFloat scrollSpeedNotAbs = (distance * 10) / 1000; //in pixels per millisecond

        CGFloat scrollSpeed = fabsf(scrollSpeedNotAbs);
        if (scrollSpeed > 0.5) {
            isScrollingFast = YES;
            NSLog(@"Fast");
        } else {
            isScrollingFast = NO;
            NSLog(@"Slow");
        }        

        lastOffset = currentOffset;
        lastOffsetCapture = currentTime;
    }
}
```

And from this i'm getting pixels per millisecond, which if is greater than 0.5, i've logged as fast, and anything below is logged as slow.

I use this for loading some cells on a table view animated. It doesn't scroll so well if I load them when the user is scrolling fast.

Comment: brilliant, this was exactly what i was planning.

Comment: thanks for a nice solution, the only thing I'd change is replace 0.1 with `captureInterval` const and than use it also in calculation of `scrollSpeedNotAbs` to increase readability of the algorithm (as the brain stops on `* 10` because general formula of speed is distance / time).

Comment: wonderful extension to the scrollview / collectionView ! Saved my day :-)

Comment: While this is not incorrect, I put in the modern solution to this very old question down the bottom.  Cheers

Comment: @Fattie I just tried this and it seems to work fine. Why did you say that it's not correct

Comment: @LanceSamaria I said it is ***not*** incorrect, but it is very old fashioned, slow, and complicated, and does not exactly follow how it works in modern iOS.  Simply use the far easier solution below.

Answer (score 85):

There's an easier way: check the UISCrollview's pan gesture recognizer. With it, you can get the velocity like so:

```
CGPoint scrollVelocity = [[_scrollView panGestureRecognizer] velocityInView:self];
```

Comment: Handy! The only downside is that `scrollVelocity` will be 0.0f immediately after the user lifts their finger (because this ends the panning gesture). So it's a good way to measure velocity while the scrollview is being dragged, but doesn't work if flicked.

Comment: ..and of course the panGestureRecognizer is only exposed in iOS 5 onwards.

Comment: is the scroll velocity a point because it records vertical and horizontal speeds?

Comment: to what @KyleFox said, yes of course true, make use of `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` to perhaps handle and velocity or offset conditions AFTER the current touch event ends

Comment: That's the velocity of the touch input, not the scrollView.

Answer (score 18):

**Converted @bandejapaisa answer to Swift 5:**

Properties used by UIScrollViewDelegate:

```
var lastOffset: CGPoint = .zero
var lastOffsetCapture: TimeInterval = .zero
var isScrollingFast: Bool = false
```

And the scrollViewDidScroll function:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let timeDiff = currentTime - lastOffsetCapture
    let captureInterval = 0.1
    
    if timeDiff > captureInterval {
        
        let distance = currentOffset.y - lastOffset.y     // calc distance
        let scrollSpeedNotAbs = (distance * 10) / 1000     // pixels per ms*10
        let scrollSpeed = fabsf(Float(scrollSpeedNotAbs))  // absolute value
        
        if scrollSpeed > 0.5 {
            isScrollingFast = true
            print("Fast")
        } else {
            isScrollingFast = false
            print("Slow")
        }
        
        lastOffset = currentOffset
        lastOffsetCapture = currentTime
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

For a simple speed calculation (All the other answers are more complicated):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat scrollSpeed = scrollView.contentOffset.y - previousScrollViewYOffset;
    previousTableViewYOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}
```

Comment: This helped me out as well, thanks!
Other people might consider throwing a fabsf() in there, just to get the absolute value.

Comment: You need to take the time into account otherwise the speed will jitter.

Comment: Other than the jittering issue, the other issue is that if I change the contentInset of the scrollView it will be registered as a fast scroll. I'm having trouble distinguishing between the two events.

Answer (score 8):

## 2017...

It's very easy to do this with modern Swift/iOS:

```
var previousScrollMoment: Date = Date()
var previousScrollX: CGFloat = 0

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
    let d = Date()
    let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(previousScrollMoment)
    let distance = (x - previousScrollX)
    let velocity = (elapsed == 0) ? 0 : fabs(distance / CGFloat(elapsed))
    previousScrollMoment = d
    previousScrollX = x
    print("vel \(velocity)")
```

Of course you want the velocity in points per second, which is what that is.

Humans drag at say 200 - 400 pps (on 2017 devices).

1000 - 3000 is a fast throw.

As it slows down to a stop, 20 - 30 is common.

So very often you will see code like this ..

```
    if velocity > 300 {
    
        // the display is >skimming<
        some_global_doNotMakeDatabaseCalls = true
        some_global_doNotRenderDiagrams = true
    }
    else {
    
        // we are not skimming, ok to do calculations
        some_global_doNotMakeDatabaseCalls = false
        some_global_doNotRenderDiagrams = false
    }
```

This is the basis for "skimming engineering" on mobiles.  (Which is a large and difficult topic.)

Note that that is not a complete skimming solution; you also have to care for unusual cases like "it has stopped" "the screen just closed" etc etc.

Answer (score 6):

May be this would be helpful

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

Comment: want to mention, this is example from velocity output: `(0.0,-5.35356)`. Scroll by y axis, 5.35.. -> 15 points per `scrollViewDidScroll` calling :) So, 5 is very fast.

Answer (score 3):

You can see [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795) sample code about how to get the contentOffset of scrollview.

The `contentOffset` on movement can be obtained from `UIScrollViewDelegate` method, named `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`, by querying `scrollView.contentOffset`. Current speed can be calculated by delta_offset and delta_time.

- Delta_offset = current_offset - pre_offset;
- Delta_time   = current_time - pre_time;

Comment: Oh I gotcha so real time velocity using distance over time I suppose

Comment: The current time can be obtained by CACurrentMediaTime() in the QuartzCore framework. Then you can calculate velocity by distance and time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another smart way to do this in SWIFT :-

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if velocity.y > 1.0 || velocity.y < -1.0 && self.sendMessageView.isFirstResponder() {
        // Somthing you want to do when scrollin fast.
        // Generally fast Vertical scrolling.
    }
}
```

So if you scrolling vertically you should use velocity.y and also if you are scrolling horizontally you should use velocity.x . Generally if value is more than 1 and less than  -1, it represent generally fast scrolling. So you can change the speed as you want. +value means scrolling up and -value means scrolling down.

Comment: How to adjust the speed?

Comment: What do you mean ? :)

Comment: you said in your answer `So you can change the speed as you want`. So i was wondering, how do you change the speed of the scroll?

Comment: I mean user scrolling speed. This functions if loop capture the scrolling speed, so i mean that you can change that speed. You can't change scrolling speed :)

Comment: This is only relevant when the view has been thrown by the finger.