# See how fast a user scrolls a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, uiscrollview, frame-rate

I have a UIScrollView with horizontal paging and about 50 pages... is there any way to detect how fast a user scrolls (in seconds)? (Like at the moment of their finger releasing how many second it is taking for the UIScrollView to go from one page to the next at the current scroll speed.

Hmmmm...

Comment: See if this is any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719753/iphone-uiscrollview-speed-check.

Answer (score 0):

I think i may be wrong but can you please check this property of `SCROLLVIEW`.

```
@property(nonatomic) float decelerationRate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
```

Comment: Bummer... as it turns out that is just a property that affects the rate at which a UIScrollView decelerates... I did find my answer in the link posted below my answer in the comments section! Thanks anyways though! :)