# How to smoothly scroll in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, xcode6

I have searched all the web but not able to find any solution for my problem.

Every where I see how to Deaccelerate the speed of Scrolling.

But I want different.

Well Here is my problem:

I have an `Scrollview` having Paging `Disabled`. Everything works fine when user `scrolls` normally. But when he/she `swipes` with force or you can say a rapid `swipe` then scroll view accelerates too fast and `skips` many content.

I want to behave normally even when user do a rapid `swipe`. How Can I acheive this.

Comment: That is normally. Scroll views accelerate faster the more and the more aggressively the user swipes...

Comment: you can use scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal; in first
also check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719753/iphone-uiscrollview-speed-check

Comment: I have tried that..both of them..but nothing works... @MohamadFarhand